# How to solve infeasible cplex model in GAMS?

Tags: modeling, cplex, gams, irreducible-infeasible-subset

I am facing this kind of error

> "Row 'eq1(14)' infeasible, all entries at implied bounds"

in a problem that a GAMS script gets data from MATLAB. I have seen some posts about conflict refiner (e.g., irreducible infeasible subset), but I really can not understand the way it is going to work what am I passing as an argument and whether I write this command in GAMS or in MATLAB and how exactly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I've not worked with the GAMS/Matlab interface, but iis is a CPLEX option and not a GAMS option. So when you're in GAMS, you just need to put it in a cplex option file (i.e., cplex.opt that is by default put in the GAMS projdir folder). If you're calling a gms file from Matlab, you can create the option file as I described and add a `model.optfile = 1;` line to your GAMS code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time. For anyone that faces the same problem this video is really useful to be considered : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHazBGYdfe4&list=PLZJUlAAb4I2ds546kdfHQ7nNeoeiIZhEU&index=13&t=235s